# Unable to install WxPerl module

Tags: perl, activeperl, wxperl

I am trying to install WxPerl in ActivePerl but the module just won't install.

I am following installation guide here http://www.wxperl.it/p/download.html

I'm on Windows 10 64 bit and using Activeperl Community Edition 5.26.0 64 bit

I tried command below but WxPerl module was not added to ActivePerl modules.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ppm repo add wxPerl http://www.wxperl.co.uk/repo29
Downloading ActiveState Package Repository packlist...not found
Downloading wxPerl packlist...done
Updating wxPerl database...done
Repo 3 added.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ppm.wxperl.it/ →

> Perl Supported: 5.8 - 5.16

Either you downgrade or ask mdootson to package for newer versions.

Comment: Thanks daxim. I downgraded and able to install Wx module but I still cannot use it. Please see error below.

“Cant’ load ‘C:/Perl/site/lib/auto/Wx/Wx.dll’ for module Wx:load_file:The specified module could not be found at C:/Perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 191.

Comment: I have since opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47615672/unable-to-run-perl-code-generated-from-wxglade